# Cannot access my own web page

Tags: http

I am developing, learning and experimenting with php,html,javascript,flash and so on.
Having web hosting and all of the cpanel, phpmyadmin and other utilities.

One day, while updating information, connection between my computer and website just went down. I found out that it is only from this computer, where I cannot access anything.

I don't know what is the reason I cannot access website, however this is what I have checked so far:

- Everything else opens normally, having problem only with my page.
- Cannot access FTP,cpanel or any kind of information related to the domain and hosting
- ipconfigs detects IP, but shows request timed out (so its not browser related)
- Turned off Firewall,AV, Rebooted computer
- Cleared caches,temp,cookies,histry with CCleaner
- Checked connectivity with both (wired,wireless) networks
- ISP has dynamic IP that has been changed about 3 times since issue
- Checked host file

I am out of ideas and understanding what could cause this kind of issue, however couple minutes ago, found out that everything works with proxy server (when adding IP and port to the browsers)

Can someone point out what should I check or try to get rid of this problem?

Also tried:

- ipconfig /flushdns
- removed all of the files from system32/drivers/etc

Havent found solution yet, but I am very curious of what is causing this...

Comment: Did you check DNS caching from your router?

Comment: The difference between direct and proxy conntions is the use of `hosts` file. Proxy omits `hosts`. As you are using Windows (`ipconfig` is used solely on Windows), you should check your `hosts` file once again.

Comment: Post the traceroute (`tracert xxx.com`) into your question.

Comment: I would suggest you post this in ServerFault.SE, you may be luckier in the variety of responses there.

Answer (score 3):

I asumme you are using windows.

Try to type this command, in the command line

```
C:/>ipconfig /dnsflush
```

With this action windows flushes the DNS cache

Comment: You meant `ipconfig` as `ifconfig` is used on *nix.

Comment: oh god!! you're right!! thks! @ABerezovskiy

Comment: for windows I used ipconfig /flushdns, but it didnt help!

Comment: Try to configure your dns with the dns hosts of your hosting.