# Troubleshoot connectivity to certain site

Tags: connections

This is related to this problem of mine: [cannot access my own web page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35262/cannot-access-my-own-web-page/35268) The question is:

Are there any tools or actions that I can try to determine what is blocking 
my computer from opening a certain website when other computers can open it normally?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command `c:\>tracert yourdomain.com` in the windows command line. You can see the steps from you pc to the server who hosts `yourdomain.com`

Comment: after step 16, tracert shows time out... But what does this mean?

Comment: This means that, the server of step 15 cannot do the next step. Can you paste all steps??

Comment: Run this command: tracert domain.com >> C:\traceroute.txt and then paste the text from that, at least hop 15, so we can see. We don't need most of the hops before that. But likely if you're taking that many hops you're quite far away from the datacenter and they're loosing your packets. You could contact your ISP to see if they can route you around that provider.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Proxy Sites such as http://kproxy.com/ to open up sites that you are not able to checkout normally. Mostly this fixes the issue. If you are still not able to, then checkout with your ISP provider for help.